# Como usar o evento Keyup do Jquery para mostrar registros dentro de uma div vindos de um script PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, keyup

Estou trabalhando em um projeto onde gostaria que quando fosse digitar algum valor dentro de um input, fosse mostrando os registros logo abaixo do mesmo. Abaixo segue a estrutura de código que tenho até então:

index.html

```html
<div>
   <label>Pesquisar</label>
   <input type="search" id="pesquisar">            
</div>

//Div que mostra os dados relativos a consulta feita através do script filter.php

<div id="grid"></div>

<script>

$("#pesquisar").keyup(function(){

var pesquisar = $("#pesquisar").val();
       
    $.ajax({

    url:"/filter.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{pesquisar:pesquisar},
    success:function(data)
    {
    
    $('#grid').html(data);
    
    }
    
   });
  
});
</script>
```

Abaixo, o script php (**filter.php**) que consulta uma tabela chamada (**produtos_tbl**) no MySql:

**Tabela produtos_tbl**

```
prodID | nome   | preco
------------------------
001     | sapato  | 20.00
002     | calça   | 25.00
003     | Camisa  | 15.00
```

**filter.php**:

```php
<?php

include 'mysqli_connection.php'; // Script para conexão com o banco de dados

$pesquisar = $_POST['pesquisar'];

$stmt = $db -> prepare('SELECT prodID, nome, preco FROM produtos_tbl WHERE nome LIKE '%$pesquisar%'');
    
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> store_result(); 
$stmt -> bind_result($prodID, $nome, $preco);

while ($stmt -> fetch()) { 

echo '
    
<div class="card text-center m-1">
      
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">'.$nome.'</h5>
        <p class="card-text"><h5>R$ '.$preco.'</h5></p>
        <p class="card-text">Produto ID '.$prodID.'</p>
      </div>

</div>
    
    ';
    
}


?>
```

Baseando-se no script php acima, quando tento digitar alguma coisa dentro do input localizado na página index.html, ocorre o seguinte erro:

```php
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in filter.php on line 26

------------

Fatal error: Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Modulo by zero in /filter.php:26 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /filter.php on line 26
```

O que poderia ser e como posso melhorar o meu código acima para que me retorne os valores corretamente dentro da div?

Comment: Não parece ter nada errado na linha 26, mas percebi que existe uma aspa a mais no fim da query:  '%$pesquisar%' '. Você deveria escapa-la, assim: 

... WHERE nome LIKE \'%$pesquisar%\';

Comment: Mais uma coisa. A query está usando aspas simples. Nesse caso o PHP vai simplesmente ignorar suas variáveis e usar como se fossem strings.

Além disso, o bind está errado. Você não está definindo as localizações para os binds.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: o autocomplete do jquery não resolveria isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/428997/php-jquery-autocomplete-din%c3%a2mico

Comment: Vou tentar adaptar o Jquery Autocomplete em uma outra página de busca. Também encontrei o Bootstrap 3 - Typeahead, porém parece que esta descontinuado para novas versões do bootstrap.

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback pessoal. O problema estava na concatenação da variável dentro da query conforme mencionado pelo Franklin Barreto. O correto é: "%'.$pesquisar.'%".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está com problema de concatenação. Troque o script

```
$stmt = $db -> prepare('SELECT prodID, nome, preco FROM produtos_tbl WHERE nome LIKE '%$pesquisar%'');
```

por

```
$stmt = $db -> prepare('SELECT prodID, nome, preco FROM produtos_tbl WHERE nome LIKE "%'.$pesquisar.'%"');
```

Comment: Obrigado Franklin. O problema era mesmo. Valeu!